# web user control changing dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

my structure is like this:
master page
  aspx(web form)
    ascx(user control)

I have a master with a menu:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
<Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Parameters" Value="Parameters">
                   <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Default" Value="def" />
    </asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Inside the MenuItem there's got to be a link to these usercontrols that i want to load on my default.aspx

I have to diferent user controls:

user control 1:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucTest1.ascx.cs" Inherits="ucTest1" %>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="TEST 1 ASCX"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

user control 2:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucTest2.ascx.cs" Inherits="ucTest2" %>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="TEST 2 ASCX"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is my Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ucTest1.ascx" TagName="ucTest1" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <uc1:ucTest1 ID="ucTest1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

it works good so far but i want to make those menuitems on my master page to switch between these two user controls in the same Default.aspx.
so when i click on test1-menuitem it brings me the ucTest1 into my default.aspx and when clicking the test2-menuitem brings me the uctest2 into my default.aspx too.

i dont know if this can be done. I'd really appreciate your help!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the QueryString to determine which user control to display. For example:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/default.aspx?uc=test" ...>
```

Set the default visibility of the user controls to false, and on `Page_Load` use a little logic to determine which control should be visible:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        switch (UserControlType)
        {
            case "test":
                ucTest1.Visible = true;
            ...
        }
    }
}

private string UserControlType
{
    get { return Request.QueryString["uc"]; }
}
```